# Decimal precision in numberfield - extjs . Can we remove the precision?

Tags: extjs

In ext js numberfield , there is a config decimalPrecision. By default it will take 2digit precision. I dont want the precision to apply to the field. It should be same as the value that i entered. How to do this ?

Comment: So do you want to always not show decimals, or only show if you enter a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a textfield with `maskRe` config option. In that case you have full control over the decimal precision. The downside is that you loose the spin buttons.

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'number',
    fieldLabel: 'Number',
    maskRe: new RegExp("[0-9.]+")
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ihn

Another option is to dynamically set the precision depending on the number of decimals after the '.'. I created a fiddle: In the "test number" field enter any number with decimal precision, press "Fill number field" and the numberfield below will be filled with the value and the entered precision.
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ihp